Making a Sign Chart with + and - Automatically Filled
I am trying to create a sign chart like this:


The key is the -'s, +'s and 0 and undefined that appears above the line.
I am trying to recreate this in TikZ. I did not find a simple way to add these kind of "filled" stuff.
Anyone suggest me a method?
Thanks everyone.
Edit: I am using TikZIt to draw this simple one. Here's the code output by it:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
    \node [style=none] (0) at (-8, 0) {};
    \node [style=none] (1) at (8.25, 0) {};
    \node [style=green dot, label={below:$-2$}] (2) at (-2.25, 0) {};
    \node [style=green dot, label={below:$-1$}] (3) at (-0.25, 0) {};
    \node [style=green dot, label={below:$-1$}] (4) at (3, 0) {};
    \node [style=none] (5) at (-2.25, 1.25) {0};
    \node [style=none] (6) at (-0.25, 1.25) {0};
    \node [style=none] (7) at (3, 1.25) {0};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
    \draw [style=new edge style 0] (0.center) to (1.center);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

The output is


Hmm, would you mind writing a short MWE with the other parts, excepting the filled pluses and minuses? This would make it more accessible to  answerers.

What is non-difficult? Draw two lines, define some styles, use \foreach several times. No big deal. Even not too many lines of code.

@Jasper I am using TikZIt. Added an output by it.

@Xintong Thank you for updating with an example. It seems that you want to connect the 0's with evenly spaced pluses and minuses. This can now be added by someone who knows how to do that, without having to write the rest of the code. By the way, you should complete the document with a \documentclass and a \begin{document}, so we are all on the same page. Best!

Observations: Looks like TikzIt "loves" using layers. Though that may be systematic, it makes code in your still quite simple drawings more difficult than it should be. // Suggestions: Unless you are building diagrams with thousands of components I suggest to spend some time on trying and learning Tikz directly via https://tikz.dev/. E.g. look up the keywords I put: \draw, \foreach, ./style={ }, later (new) arrows.meta, and from Tom's approach anchor= (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/732156/245790). You'll do much better, soon.

Interesting topic. I would like to give it a try:
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.618cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick,<->] (-7,0) -- (7,0); 
\foreach \x in {-4,...,5}{
\draw (\x,0) -- ++ (0,0.15);
\ifnum\fpeval{\x}<0\relax%
\node at (\x,0) [anchor=north,below=0.1cm,xshift=-0.14cm] {$\x$};\else
\node at (\x,0) [anchor=north,below=0.1cm] {$\x$};\fi
\ifnum\fpeval{(\x+3)*(\x-4)*(\x-1)}=0\relax%
\fill (\x,0) circle [radius=0.075cm];
\ifnum\fpeval{\x-1}=0\relax%
\node (ud) at (\x,0) [anchor=south,above=0.8cm] {undefined};%
\draw ([yshift=0.25cm]\x,0) -- (ud);
\else\node at (\x,0) [anchor=south,above=0.2cm] {$0$};\fi%
\fi%
}
\foreach \x in {-7,-6.5,...,7}{%
\ifdim\fpeval{(\x+3)*(\x-4)*(\x-1)}pt=0pt\relax%
\else\ifdim\fpeval{((\x+3)*(\x-4))/(\x-1)}pt<0pt\relax
\node at (\x,0) [anchor=south,above=0.2cm,blue!80] {$-$};\else%
\node at (\x,0) [anchor=south,above=0.2cm,red!80] {$+$};
\fi\fi%
}
\node at (-6,1) {$\frac{(x+3)(x-4)}{(x-1)}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Nice. // Three remarks. 1) I‘d use some indentation to see the codes structure more easily. 2) I would introduce a few ./style commands to clean up code, which makes it easier to read, too. 3) It may be evident then, that one or few \newcommand s for repeated code structures will improve it even more.

Well, a few more observations. Your approach works, but it will be hard to tell the various \if-cases apart, let alone introduce modifications. E.g. using a polynom in an \if just to know when to place 3 circles can be perceived as genious or obscure. I think code will be much clearer to follow when you simply use about 5 simple \foreach loops in contrast to your 2. Though your code is compact, I think such a direction should be avoided, when it comes to clarity, quality, and: novices.

@MS-SPO Good suggestions. I will improve it when I get a chance.

With tikzset, I define the style.
The roots, positive and negative areas are found "by hand".
For "undefined", I add a \decal parameter, in case there are several "undefined" close together.
The code
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    dot/.style = {
        circle, 
        fill        =#1, 
        inner sep   =1.5pt,
        },
    undefined/.style={
        dot=red,
        label= {[yshift=#1]above:undefined}
        },
    nul/.style      ={
        dot=cyan,
        label= {[yshift=+2mm]above:$\mathstrut 0$}
        },
    +/.style        ={
        label= {[yshift=+2mm]above:$\mathstrut +$}
        },
    -/.style        ={
        label= {[yshift=+2mm]above:$\mathstrut -$}
        }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [thick,<->] (-7,0) -- (7,0); 
    \foreach \n in {-4,...,5}{
        \draw (\n,0) node[below]{$\n$}-- ++ (0,0.1);
    }
    \foreach \x  in {-7,-6.5,...,-3.5,-2.5,1.5,2,...,3.5}{      
        \node [-] at (\x,0) {};
    }
    \foreach \x  in {-2.5,-2,...,0.5,4.5,5,...,7}{      
        \node [+] at (\x,0) {};
    }
    \foreach \x  in {-3,4}{      
        \node [nul] at (\x,0) {};
    }
    \foreach \x/\decal  in {1/8mm}{      
        \node[undefined=\decal](U)  at(\x,0) {};
        \draw [thick](U) --+ (0,\decal);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Nice and clean
